# Impute variables within a data.frame group by factor column

Tags: r

I have a data.frame contain numeric columns, these columns have factor levels that I want to impute missing values by...let me explain.

```
part   id   value
a      1     23.4
a      2     23.8
a      3     45.6
a      4     34.7
a      5     Na
b      1     45.2
b      2     34.6
b      3     Na
b      4     30.9
b      5     28.1
```

Id like to impute the NA values with the mean of the part. So for part a, I'd like to impute the id 5 missing value with the mean of ids 1-4 in part a, and same for part b, impute missing id3 with the mean of ids in part b etc.

I need to do this across many columns (imagine having many more value columns). So perhaps an apply with a function etc.

Comment: You could avoid reading the numeric columns as factors by using `na.strings='Na'` in the read.table/read.csv

Comment: Also, consider missForest package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `na.strings` argument in `read.table/read.csv` we can convert the missing values to real `NA` and thereby reading the 'value' columns as 'numeric'.  With `dplyr`, we can change `replace` the `NAs` in multiple value columns with `mean` of that column.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(part) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(replace(., which(is.na(.)), mean(., na.rm=TRUE))), 
       starts_with('value'))
```

Or a similar option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- grep('value', names(df1))
setDT(df1)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD,  function(x) replace(x,
     which(is.na(x)), mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))), by = part,.SDcols=nm1]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- read.table(text="part   id   value
a      1     23.4
a      2     23.8
a      3     45.6
a      4     34.7
a      5     Na
b      1     45.2
b      2     34.6
b      3     Na
b      4     30.9
b      5     28.1", header=TRUE, na.strings="Na", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this...if the value column (of which there are many) have different names - how could that be handled ..col3=value, but col4=nextvalue, col5=adiffvalue etc etc...

Comment: @PaulBeales It is not a problem.  You can remove `starts_with` and use `col3:col5`  or some of the methods described in `?select` for selecting columns

Comment: @PaulBeales I thought the column names are `col3`, `col4` etc.  In your case, it should be either `contains('value')` or `ends_with('value')`

Comment: thanks...this is what i needed...appreciate it - tick marked..!